# Get-Printer cmdlet applied to multiple remote servers

Tags: powershell, printing

I'm trying to run the cmdlet "Get-Printer" and apply it to multiple computers but I get an error message I tried using double quotations marks and get a same error message.

**"Get-Printer : Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'ComputerName'. Cannot convert value to type System.String."**

```
Get-Printer -ComputerName 'server01', 'server02'|select-object -Property Name, PortName |Select-String -Pattern 127.0.0.1
```

is it because get-printer cmdlet can only be applied to one server at a time? do I have to take a different approach to be able to apply it to multiple servers?

Comment: ComputerName is a string not an array. You have to do each one individually. See the documentation for [Get-Printer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/printmanagement/get-printer?view=windowsserver2019-ps)

Comment: Thank you. I know taking a different approach means it might need a more advanced coding, how can I have that done? I'm barely learning and I couldn't find a lot of information online on how to apply it to multiple servers

Comment: You can just use another pipe at the beginning. Try `'server01', 'server02' | %{Get-Printer -ComputerName $_}`

Comment: your code also worked like a charm thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ComputerName` is a string not an array. See the documentation for [Get-Printer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/printmanagement/get-printer?view=windowsserver2019-ps).

You can however use another pipe (`|`) at the beginning followed by a block beginning with a `%` (shorthand for `ForEach-Object`) in order to feed the strings to the cmdlet one at a time. It would look something like this:

```
'server01', 'server02' | 
    %{Get-Printer -ComputerName $_} | 
    Select-Object -Property Name, PortName |
    Select-String -Pattern 127.0.0.1
```

There is a second issue with this though. `Select-String` also expects a string, but you're passing it an object containing `Name` and `PortName`. Instead of using `Select-String`, you could probably just pipe it to a block prefixed by `?` (shorthand for `Where-Object`) and check if `PortName` contains 127.0.0.1.

Adding this would look like:

```
'server01', 'server02' | 
    %{Get-Printer -ComputerName $_} | 
    Select-Object -Property Name, PortName |
    ?{$_.PortName.Contains("127.0.0.1")}
```

If you would like, you can also shorten `Select-Object` to just `Select`, but I'll leave that up to you.

Comment: your line of code also worked like a charm Thank you. Any recommendations in how or where I can learn how to properly structure the code like yours? right now I'm just working in single strings and get to roadblocks such as the one I found out today.

Comment: The main thing is to get familiar with the different types and how they function. Research arrays, strings, integers, and booleans first, then move to complex types like lists and dictionaries. After that, all you really need is to become familiar with common cmdlets like `Where-Object`, `ForEach-Object`, `Select-Object`, etc. Also research how [pipes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pipelines?view=powershell-7.2) work. You can use these with any command, including the ones mentioned above.

Comment: For more complex programming, you will need to know how variables, for loops, and foreach loops work as well, but I would hold off on that until you have a grasp on arrays and know how the primitive types (strings, integers, booleans) are used.

Answer (score 0):

The help of Get-Printer shows that the parameter -ComputerName accepts input of type string, but not string array. So you can only specify a single computer name.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/printmanagement/get-printer?view=windowsserver2019-ps

What you can do however, is to define the array of computer names first and then use a foreach.

```
$computers = "server01","server02"
foreach($computer in $computers)
{
    Get-Printer -ComputerName $computer |select-object -Property Name, PortName | Select-String -Pattern 127.0.0.1
}
```

Or like Jesse suggested above a one liner would look like this:

```
"server01","server02" | ForEach-Object {Get-Printer -ComputerName $_} | Select-Object -Property Name, PortName | Select-String -Pattern 127.0.0.1
```

Comment: Let me try and come up with something I'll post an edit shortly. thank you

Comment: Your code worked like a charm I have never tried that approach I'm still learning and sometimes I find it difficult to find the correct approach or how to properly structure the strings. Do you have any advice on how or where to learn about setting string arrays?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want to know how to find out if you can use an array or a single string.
Best is to look at the CmdLet help by executing 
"help get-printer -Parameter computername"
for example. The output shows that the parameter "ComputerName" will accept input of type "<string>" (single). If a parameter accepts an array, it would display "<string[]>".

Comment: Sorry if i didn't explain myself properly, I just want to learn the proper way to write the code or the structure like I knew about foreach but I didn't know how to structure it like the way you did it